# React native testing - How to get last rendered version of object in jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test that a component's prop values are correct. The component is like so:

```
export const myComp = ({
  width,
  height,
  accessibilityLabel
}: myCompProps) => {

  const { isAllowed } = useAllowedContext();
  console.log(isAllowed, "isAllowed")

  return (
      <Video
        repeat={isAllowed}
        source={'path/to/file'}
        style={{width:width, height:height}}
        //add accessibility label prop
      />
  );
};
```

This is how I'm setting `isAllowed` to true in jest to test:

```
AccessibilityInfo.isAllowed = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true);
   
  
render( <allowedProvider > <myComp width=20 height=40 accessibilityLabel="testing"/> </allowedProvider>);
const getVideo = screen.getByLabelText('testing');

console.log(getVideo.props.repeat, "console repeat")
});
```

**The problem:** The console logs `isAllowed` in the component `false` once, and then the console logs `repeat` as `false`.
Then it logs `isAllowed` as `true` but there are no further console logs of `repeat`. Is there any way to get only the final component's `repeat` prop?

PS: `isAllowed` is just a mock name i'm using in place of the actual one

I tried setting a timeout before I render but it did not do anything

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    // expect something that's available after the timeout
}, 5000);
```

Edit: also get this warning on console

```
Warning: An update to allowedProvider inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
 |     
 |     When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
 |
```

i tried wrapping in act but im not sure how to do it correctly

Comment: Why is `AccessibilityInfo.isAllowed` a promise? Should that be `jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);`

Comment: good point, i tried that but problem remains the same. updated question with warning

Comment: how is `allowedProvider` implemented and how does it interact with the value of `AccessibilityInfo.isAllowed`?

Comment: Its a bit hard to explain, but essentially it checks the value of `await AccessibilityInfo.isAllowed();`
Also apologies, i had been staring at the code for too long and did not realize that multiple console logs were due to other tests running. Please check my updated problem in question

Comment: How about waiting for the promise to resolve after rendering the component just like you do in your implementation? ```await AccessibilityInfo.isAllowed()``` You can then make assertions on the props